# R insert string column into Oracle database

Tags: r, string, oracle, odbc

I am trying to insert values into an existing table in Oracle database from R via ODBC by running the following command,

```
conODBC<-odbcConnect(dsn="xxxx", uid="xxxxx", pwd="xxxx", readOnly=FALSE)
sqls<-sprintf("INSERT INTO R_AAAA (AAA,AAB,AAC,AAD) VALUES (%s)", 
              apply(R_AAAA, 1, function(i) paste(i, collapse=",")))
lapply(sqls, function(s) sqlQuery(conODBC, s))
```

And I got this error,

> "HY000 984 [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-00984: 列在此处不允许\n"

列在此处不允许 is chinese meaning 'Column is not allowed here'. And the variable sqls appears as follow,

```
>sqls

"INSERT INTO R_AAAA (AAA,AAB,AAC,AAD) VALUES
(H3E000000000000,344200402050,12,  2.347826e+01)"
```

Column AAA in R_AAAA is a string column. It appears to me Oracle database needs single quotes ' around a string value, `'H3E000000000000'` for instance, in an insert statement. Anyone knows how to add single marks? I would like to insert rows into an existing table instead of creating a new table in Oracle with sqlSave.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can preprocess R_AAAA by adding ' to character columns before calling the code

```
R_AAAA <- data.frame(AAA="H3E000000000000", AAB=344200402050, AAC=12,  AAD=2.347826e+01)

as.data.frame(lapply(R_AAAA, function(x) {
    if (class(x) == "character") {
        x <- paste0("'",x,"'")   
    }
    x
}))
```

what R package are you for the sqlSave? There should be an option to insert new rows e.g. `append=TRUE`.

Answer (score 0):

Preprocessing works. I use RODBC package. If I create an empty R_AAAA in oracle database and run the command in R

`sqlSave(conODBC,R_AAAA,tablename="R_AAAA",append=TRUE)`

R-studio crashes. There wasnt even an error message:)